# How to feed spaCy pipeline asynchronously?

Tags: python, spacy

I would like to setup a spaCy pipeline which does some parsing and annotations.
Source of my documents is a remote storage, therefore obtaining the documents is relatively expensive.

As I want to annotate a lot of documents, I would like to process them in a streaming way asynchronously.

While setting up my pipeline as usual, the code first obtains all documents to then parse it in the pipeline.
How can I stream the documents into the pipeline?

```
import spacy

def get_docs_from_remote(size):
    // obtain number of documents from remote storage
    for document in result:
        yield(document['text'])

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable=["ner", "lemmatizer"])
docs = nlp.pipe(
    get_docs_from_remote(
        size=number_of_documents,
    )
)

for doc in docs:
    // do stuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there any errors with this code? It looks fine, e.g.:

```py
import spacy
import time


def get_docs_from_remote(size):
    for i in range(size):
        time.sleep(2)
        yield str(i)


nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable=["ner", "lemmatizer"])
docs = nlp.pipe(
    get_docs_from_remote(
        size=10,
    ),
    batch_size=2,
)

for doc in docs:
    print(doc.text)
```

The main thing to be aware of with generators and `nlp.pipe` is that it waits for full batches before processing the docs.

`batch_size=2` above is just for demo purposes. Normally the default of `256` is fine and it could be higher if you have more RAM. On the other hand if your docs load more slowly than `nlp` can process them and you'd rather have the results sooner, you can even switch to `batch_size=1`, but the overall time spent processing will be much higher.